# Is a stochastic process, which is defined via the conditional expectation of a strictly postive random variable, strictly positive almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $T\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, $[0,T]$ be a time-index set and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. We endow the latter with a filtration $\mathbb{F}$ which is the augmented filtration generated by a Brownian motion $W$. We define:

- A random variable $A$ such that $A(\omega)>1$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.
- A stochastic process $B:=(B_{t})_{t\in[0,T]}$ where $B_{t}:=\mathbb{E}[A\,\vert\,\mathcal{F}_{t}]$.

Is this reasoning correct: By the monotonicity of conditional expectation we can deduce that $B_{t}\neq 0$ for every $t\in[0,T]$, $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. However, we cannot deduce that $B_{t}\neq 0$, $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. for every $t\in[0,T]$, since an uncountable union of null-sets is not necessarily a null-set. In particular, we might have a situation where each path of $B$ is at least once equal to zero.

Is there a possibility to get the implication mentioned above? Maybe via continuity of the martingale $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard assumption is to assume that the process has (almost all )paths that are continuous from the right (or from the left). If we assume that (with probability $1$) $B_s \to B_t$ as $ s$ decreases to $t$ (for any $t$) then the we get $B_t \geq 1$  for all rational $t$ with probability $1$ which implies $B_t \geq 1$  for all $t$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have two questions concerning your answer: First, am I correct: For your first argument we do not necessarily need continuity. We could just use my argument above. However, we need continuity to deduce that for a sequence of rational $(t_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and an irrational $s$ we have $\vert t_{n}-s\vert<\delta \implies \vert B_{t_{n}}-B_{s}\vert <\epsilon$. Second, am I correct: By Ito's representation theorem $B$ has a continuous modification. However, in our case, choosing this modification is not enough. We need to assume that $B$ is (right-) cont.